# How can I represent large amount of time using joda-time

Tags: jodatime, period

I'm trying to represent the value 3419779 (in seconds) in hours minutes and seconds however using Period of joda time returns -243h-06min-28, What can I use to represent this in the correct form that would be around 950 hours x min y sec?

I discover what I was doing wrong, I had multiplied seconds * 1000 returning a negative int because the result was very big, to correct i did seconds * 1000L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover what I was doing wrong, I had multiplied seconds * 1000 returning a negative int because the result was very big, to correct i did seconds * 1000L.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an integer overflow as noted above. Please mark the question as answered.